# Vue and Json-server hosted on Vercel

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vercel, json-server

I'm currently writing frontend app in Vue.js. Until I have a real web API, I've decided to use [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). Now I'm trying to configure [Vercel](https://vercel.com) to start my json-server alongside Vue during deployment. Using `concurrently "json-server --watch db.json" "npm run build` as override for build command results in json-server starting. However, build command reports `npm run build exited with code 0` and then deployment continues to run until some timeout kills it. Nothing is deployed. How can I make it work? I don't need the json-server to be visible outside, just that my app can communicate with it on Vercel server.

edit:

just realized it's impossible to run it the way I've tried. Node will await json-server's closure, so deployment script will never finish, thus timeout.

What I'm trying to do now is to run json-server inside vue app, i.e. running something like this

```
import jsonServer from 'json-server';
const server = jsonServer.create();
const jsonRouter = jsonServer.router('db.json');
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(jsonRouter);
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('JSON Server is running');
});
```

inside main.ts. The problem is I get error:

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js

Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

How can I fix that? Is it going to work, anyway?

edit2:

I ended up deploying separately to [Heroku](https://heroku.com) with script that runs only the json-server, and then using heroku url to act as pseudo-backend.